# An approach to Andrica's conjecture

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

[Andrica's conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AndricasConjecture.html) states that $\sqrt{p_{n+1}}-\sqrt{p_n} < 1$.

but solving for $n=1,2,\dotsc$ yields

n=1, $\sqrt{p_{2}}-\sqrt{p_1} < 1$=>$\sqrt{p_{2}}<\sqrt{p_1}+1$

n=2, $\sqrt{p_{3}}-\sqrt{p_2} < 1$=>$\sqrt{p_{3}}<\sqrt{p_2}+1=>\sqrt{p_{2}}>\sqrt{p_3}-1$

implies $\sqrt{p_1}>\sqrt{p_3}-2$

.

.

.

continue with the same we have,

$\sqrt{p_{n+1}} < (n+\sqrt{2})$ or

$p_{n+1} < (n+\sqrt{2})^2$  which is obviously true

as $p_{n+1}$ according to Pierre Dusart is
$p_{n+1} < (n+1)\ln\left((n+1)\ln(n+1)\right)$

Please elaborate how I am wrong !

Comment: It is easily solved if Oppermann's Conjecture is true. Unfortunately, Oppermann's is not easy to solve.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101014/fundamental-problems-whose-solution-seems-completely-out-of-reach/101133#101133

Answer (score 3):

Your logic feeling is wrong: Assuming $\pi^2>10$ you can easily prove that $\pi>3$, which is true; but in fact $\pi^2< 10$.

Same thing with Andrica's conjecture: If it is false, anything (like $1=0$) can be derived from it, but when it is true it only implies true things. Therefore the true consequence you derived is no corroboration of the conjecture.

Comment: also how can we 'easily' prove from pi^2 > 10 that pi > 3 ..??

Answer (score 3):

You have just shown that we cannot arrive at a contradiction of Andrica's conjecture using this method.
But this doesn't mean that actually Andrica's conjecture ***is*** true.
If you are not a mathematician, it was a nice effort.

Comment: thanks for that as I am not, but in set-theory we have been taught that if A is true then arguments following A are also true, please elaborate...

Comment: @ShivanshuSrivastava yes. Also,if an argument following A is wrong then A must be wrong.You have shown that an argument is true which shows that A is not obviously wrong.But we need to show that A is true.